# How do you train a model with low success rate?

Tags: training

I'm training a model where the samples success rate is low.

I mean how do I tackle such situation - maybe only show the samples which match but then the ones that doesn't may match too.

But on the other hand if I train it with all the samples it seems like it never fully matches when it should.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need to specify your question: What do you mean by 'samples success rate', 'samples that match' and what is 'it' referring to in 'seems like it never fully matches when it should'?.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you referring to something related to class imbalance?

Answer (score 1):

You have a situation where class imbalance is quite high. There are two ways to tackle this:

1. Use Focal loss which focuses on underrepresented classes.
2. Train a Siamese network and allied techniques to it.